# How to group every other unique value in pandas dataframe outside top 5 values (by size) into an 'Other' category for plotting and tabling?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a column `Order` with over 75 unique values of items (`Clothes`, `Appliances`, `Electronics`, etc.) and over 1000 entries in total. When I try to plot any descriptive statistics on a graph over a period of time (important: not all order items are non-zero in all periods of time), it becomes hard to read the graph because of how small some of the values are in comparison to others.

For that reason I think it would be better for me to just show the values of the top 3-5 order items (by size/count) and then group the rest into a category called `Other` just for plotting and groupby/pivot tabling purposes.

I guess I could map the values, but that is too time consuming, and it would also require me to change the existing values for the non top 3-5 represented entries - which is not something that I want to do.

How would I do that?

```
Sample data
Year    Month        Type          cancelled 
2012      1        electronics       yes
2012      10         fiber           yes
2012      9         clothes          no
2013      4        vegetables        yes
2013      5        appliances        no
2016      3        fiber             no
2017      1        clothes           yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
print (df)
    Year  Month         Type cancelled
0   2012      1  electronics       yes
1   2012      1        fiber       yes
2   2012      3      clothes        no
3   2012      3   vegetables       yes
4   2012      3   appliances        no
5   2012      3        fiber        no
6   2012      1      clothes       yes
7   2012      1  electronics       yes
8   2012      1        fiber       yes
9   2012      1      clothes        no
10  2012      3   vegetables       yes
11  2012      3   appliances        no
12  2012      3        fiber        no
13  2012      1      clothes       yes
14  2012      1  electronics       yes
15  2012      1        fiber       yes
16  2012      1      clothes        no
17  2012      1   vegetables       yes
18  2012      3   appliances        no
19  2012      3        fiber        no
20  2012      1      clothes       yes
```

Idea is create top3 value per groups by `Year` and `Month`:

```
N = 3
df1 = (df.groupby(['Year', 'Month'])['Type'].value_counts()
         .groupby(level=[0,1]).head(N)
          .reset_index(name='count')
         )
print (df1)
   Year  Month         Type  count
0  2012      1      clothes      5
1  2012      1  electronics      3
2  2012      1        fiber      3
3  2012      3   appliances      3
4  2012      3        fiber      3
5  2012      3   vegetables      2
```

Then `merge` to original by left join and replace `other` to values with no in top3 by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
df = df.merge(df1, how='left')
df['Type'] = df['Type'].mask(df.pop('count').isna(), 'other')
print (df)
    Year  Month         Type cancelled
0   2012      1  electronics       yes
1   2012      1        fiber       yes
2   2012      3      clothes        no
3   2012      3   vegetables       yes
4   2012      3   appliances        no
5   2012      3        fiber        no
6   2012      1      clothes       yes
7   2012      1  electronics       yes
8   2012      1        fiber       yes
9   2012      1      clothes        no
10  2012      3   vegetables       yes
11  2012      3   appliances        no
12  2012      3        fiber        no
13  2012      1      clothes       yes
14  2012      1  electronics       yes
15  2012      1        fiber       yes
16  2012      1      clothes        no
17  2012      1   vegetables       yes
18  2012      3   appliances        no
19  2012      3        fiber        no
20  2012      1      clothes       yes
```

If need replace all values without top3 not per groups:

```
N = 3
s = df['Type'].value_counts().head(N)
print (s)
clothes       6
fiber         6
appliances    3
Name: Type, dtype: int64

df['Type'] = df['Type'].where(df['Type'].isin(s.index), 'other')
print (df)
    Year  Month        Type cancelled
0   2012      1       other       yes
1   2012      1       fiber       yes
2   2012      3     clothes        no
3   2012      3       other       yes
4   2012      3  appliances        no
5   2012      3       fiber        no
6   2012      1     clothes       yes
7   2012      1       other       yes
8   2012      1       fiber       yes
9   2012      1     clothes        no
10  2012      3       other       yes
11  2012      3  appliances        no
12  2012      3       fiber        no
13  2012      1     clothes       yes
14  2012      1       other       yes
15  2012      1       fiber       yes
16  2012      1     clothes        no
17  2012      1       other       yes
18  2012      3  appliances        no
19  2012      3       fiber        no
20  2012      1     clothes       yes
```